# Common Login Between iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just want if a user has been login into one of my iphone app and choose remember me. It should be remember between all of my apps installed in his iphone.

In simple world I use **NSUserDefaults** to perform remember me. I want a common place to get/set **UserName** and **password** between all my apps.

All my application uses a single web service method to perform login.

Is it possible? If yes will apple approve so?

If there is any other way to perform this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, you will have to save the data in the KeyChain.

You will need to configure your apps to share a keychain acces.
[Here](http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/) you will find a nice tutorial on how to do this.